CSS only / basic JS solution to align secondary links overlay with main link on hover
I have created this codepen: https://codepen.io/AnkitaSood/pen/dyEWNaB
This is the basic template of the navigation with main links and secondary links:
<nav>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="main-link-container">
            <a href='#' class="main-link">Link 1</a>
            <div class="secondary-links">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
...
 </ul>

I would like to make the nav scroll-able on overflow of y-axis. I also want to be able to display the secondary-links always on hover. Currently on hover of the last main-link, not all of the secondary-links associated with it aren't getting displayed. I want that container to be aligned such that the bottom of that container is aligned with the bottom of the last main link like in the screenshot:


What do you want to happen if there isn't room for the whole sublink list to be shown in the viewport?

You can easily achieve that by simply switching out top: 0 in the positioning of the sub-menus, with bottom: 0. But then you will of course easily get a problem with the links at the top, instead of those as the bottom ...

You could make the last half of the secondary lists be placed with bottom: 0 rather than top: 0 as you know there is more space above than below them.
This snippet overrides the top: 0 with bottom: 0 for the last 5 in the list using nth-last-child(-n+5)hoas the selector.
Note that top has to be reset to initial as otherwise the top: 0 will still be honored.


a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  place-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.pages {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main-content-section {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

nav {
  background: #1e1e1e;
  min-width: 8rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.main-link-container {
  position: relative;
}

.main-link {
  color: #e0e0e0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #1a344d;
    color: #f5f5f5;
  }
  &.active {
    background-color: #353535;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    +.secondary-links {
      display: block;
      position: unset;
      background-color: unset;
    }
  }
  &:not(.active):hover+.secondary-links {
    display: block;
  }
}

.secondary-links {
  display: none;
  left: 8rem;
  min-width: max-content;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #292929;
  border-radius: 0 0.25rem 0.25rem 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  &:has(.sec-link.active) {
    display: block;
    position: unset;
    background-color: unset;
    a {
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
      margin: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
      padding: 0 0.5rem 0 2.25rem;
    }
  }
  &:has(a:hover) {
    display: block;
  }
}

li:nth-last-child(-n+5) .secondary-links {
  bottom: 0;
  top: initial;
}

.sec-link {
  color: #e0e0e0;
  display: block;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #1a344d;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  &.active {
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    margin: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
    padding: 0 0.5rem 0 2.25rem;
    background-color: #353535;
    color: #65adf6;
  }
}
<div class="root">
  <div class="pages">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="main-link-container">
            <a href='#' class="main-link">Link 1</a>
            <div class="secondary-links">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="main-link-container">
            <a href='#' class="main-link">Link 2</a>
            <div class="secondary-links">
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 1 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 2 </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="main-link-container">
            <a href='#' class="main-link">Link 3</a>
            <div class="secondary-links">
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 1 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 2 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 3 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 4 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 5 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 6 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 7 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 8 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 9 </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="main-link-container">
            <a href='#' class="main-link">Link 4</a>
            <div class="secondary-links">
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 1 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 2 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 3 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 4 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 5 </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="main-link-container">
            <a href='#' class="main-link">Link 5</a>
            <div class="secondary-links">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="main-link-container">
            <a href='#' class="main-link">Link 6</a>
            <div class="secondary-links">
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 1 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 2 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 3 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 4 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 5 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 6 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 7 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 8 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 9 </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="main-link-container">
            <a href='#' class="main-link">Link 7</a>
            <div class="secondary-links">
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 1 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 2 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 3 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 4 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 5 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 6 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 7 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 8 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 9 </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="main-link-container">
            <a href='#' class="main-link">Link 8</a>
            <div class="secondary-links">
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 1 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 2 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 3 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 4 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 5 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 6 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 7 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 8 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 9 </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="main-link-container">
            <a href='#' class="main-link">Link 9</a>
            <div class="secondary-links">
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 1 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 2 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 3 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 4 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 5 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 6 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 7 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 8 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 9 </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="main-link-container">
            <a href='#' class="main-link">Link 10</a>
            <div class="secondary-links">
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 1 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 2 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 3 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 4 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 5 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 6 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 7 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 8 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 9 </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>


        <li>
          <div class="main-link-container">
            <a href='#' class="main-link">Link 11</a>
            <div class="secondary-links">
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 1 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 2 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 3 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 4 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 5 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 6 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 7 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 8 </a>
              <a href="#" class="sec-link"> Sub link 9 </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main class="main-content">
      <section class="main-content-section">
        main content goes here
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>



Note: this still doesn't solve the problem of what should happen if there just isn't enough room for all the secondary list to be shown, but that's a different question.

The number of links that will be displayed in the navigation is variable.. sometimes there will be 5 links and other times there will be 10, so it is not easily to determine how may of the links should have bottom: 0 instead of top: 0. Makes me wonder if this is possible with CSS only. Might need some basic JS to calculate viewport height and compare with navigation height ..

Sometimes the last main-link's might only have 2 secondary links so it will be ok to display the flyout with top: 0. The ideal solution to this needs to probably calculate if the secondary-links container's height is exceeding viewport height and resulting in an overflow.
